# Reverse geocoding not working in digikam

Tags: kubuntu, kde, digikam, geolocation

Running digikam 5.6.0 on Kubuntu 18.04.

I have several images with geolocation data.

When I select these and Edit Geolocation -> Reverse Geocoding -> Open Street Map -> Apply Reverse Geocoding

It does nothing.

The terminal output (relevant part) is:

```
digikam.general: AlbumWatch use QFileSystemWatcher
digikam.geoiface: "setting backend marble"
digikam.geoiface: ----
digikam.geoiface: "ROADMAP"
digikam.geoiface: Loading GPS bookmarks from "/home/user/.local/share/digikam/geobookmarks.xml"
digikam.geoiface: 900 2100 900
digikam.geoiface: "backend marble is ready!"
digikam.geoiface: "marble:900"
digikam.geoiface: 900 2100 900
digikam.geoiface: "created cluster 0: 1 tiles"
digikam.geoiface: "level 5: 1 non empty tiles sorted into 1 clusters (1 searched)"
digikam.geoiface: "created cluster 0: 1 tiles"
digikam.geoiface: "level 5: 1 non empty tiles sorted into 1 clusters (1 searched)"
digikam.geoiface: QVariant(QPersistentModelIndex, QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,Digikam::GPSImageModel(0x55c00e9c85b0))) QSize(58, 32)
digikam.geoiface: QVariant(QPersistentModelIndex, QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,Digikam::GPSImageModel(0x55c00e9c85b0))) QSize(56, 31)
digikam.geoiface: "created cluster 0: 1 tiles"
digikam.geoiface: "level 5: 1 non empty tiles sorted into 1 clusters (1 searched)"
digikam.general: QModelIndex(0,3,0x55c011a92c90,Digikam::GPSImageSortProxyModel(0x55c011a91ca0)) QModelIndex(0,3,0x0,Digikam::GPSImageModel(0x55c00e9c85b0))
digikam.geoiface: 900 2100 900
digikam.geoiface: 900 2100 900
digikam.geoiface: "created cluster 0: 1 tiles"
digikam.geoiface: "level 5: 1 non empty tiles sorted into 1 clusters (1 searched)"
digikam.geoiface: "created cluster 0: 1 tiles"
digikam.geoiface: "level 5: 1 non empty tiles sorted into 1 clusters (1 searched)"
digikam.geoiface: "created cluster 0: 1 tiles"
digikam.geoiface: "level 5: 1 non empty tiles sorted into 1 clusters (1 searched)"
digikam.geoiface: ----
```

On the other hand, if I choose Geonames.org place name (non-US) in place of Open Street Map, it does tag the images with very limited information --- country and name of the place.

What is happening here? How do I get reverse geocoding to work?

Comment: if you start digikam with the terminal, do you see any error message coming up when clicking "Apply Reverse Geocoding" ?

Comment: If no one can help you here, this question might be better placed at the [digikam support](https://www.digikam.org/support/)

Comment: @RoVo Thanks. I have updated the question with the output on the terminal. Also, if I choose Geonames.org place name (non-US), it does attach tags. I have attached output related to that, also

Comment: did you try the current stable version 5.9.0. You can download the appimage from the website: https://download.kde.org/stable/digikam/

Comment: @RoVo OK. I tried 5.9.0. But that, too, does not tag the pictures